# Windows - Mount one drive as both C and D drive

Tags: windows

How can I mount one drive as both C and D drive ?

It is currently set as C drive, and I want to *also* mount it as D drive.

Goal is to have C and D drive pointing to same drive.

Need to do this because everyone else (using one.config file, read by IIS) uses D:\ drive (VirtualMachine) to store data
but my physical machine only have C:\ drive

To avoid modifying config file from D:\ to C:\, i want to make my setting the same as everyone else, hence this workaround.

-- update -- 
neither SUBST nor simple map network drive work with IIS,even though ApplicationPool is run with my own credentials. any idea? this mapping seems to be NOT share-able between logins/sessions

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - could you tell us what you are trying to achieve, rather than how you think you may achieve it?

Comment: @Tetsujin edited description of problem

Comment: share drive c, map drive d to it.

Comment: thanks @Larryc !! so simple. will see if it is not too slow :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SUBST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST) maps a directory as a drive. It works just as well with the root directory of a drive, so:

```
SUBST D: C:\
```

This doesn't persist across logins, so if you want it to happen each time you log in put a .BAT file in your startup folder (usually named something like c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup) containing that line.

Edit: The linked Wikipedia article also suggests a registry method that makes the substitution available to system services like IIS. In the Registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices
```

create a string value with name `D:` and data `\??\C:\`. The mapped drive should then appear at the next reboot.

Comment: neither SUBST nor simple map network drive work with IIS,even though ApplicationPool is run with my own credentials. any idea? this seems to be NOT share-able between logins/sessions

Comment: @Porton: I've added an alternative suggestion.

Comment: magic! it works with tweaking the registry setting, many thanks @john_e   :-D